# There is no way to encode video smooth streaming

Tags: expression, expression-encoder-sdk, smooth-streaming

What you need to install so I can encode video smooth streaming through the encoder? [image] - where I pointed out to be smooth streaming

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the pro version first.  And you are currently working with 3.0.  Go ahead an upgrade the versions.